# Is there a need for advanced learning resources for automation testers?

Tags: selenium, learning

I am just trying to dig as deep as I can to find the most clear-cut best practices as I can, but I am having trouble finding code or tutorials that are anything but absolute basic and then they just hand you off to "Oh here's how to add to 14 on the calculator. YOU'RE ALL SET!".

Would there be any real need for sort of an end to end tutorial/blog sort of WordPress site that would cater towards more advanced learning? I have sort of started a blog and then I totally re-designed it to start off easy enough for newer manual QA's to read it, but give them a deep, full understanding.

I am at the point now where I want to bring in a few other writer's as I am getting to the actual functional coding part now. I have a few topics in mind: Correct usage of waitforready, using if element.exist vs waitforready bool == false, Finding hidden elements in the DOM using the tree, and clear cut ways to pick reliable locators that will last.

If this is a good idea, where would I go to look for volunteers interested in writing?

Some of the current content is viewable at SmartTester.net

Comment: You are probably better off breaking this down into individual questions.   There isn't a simple "this is the right answer for everything".  Circumstances dictate decisions and, with experience, you will develop which is most appropriate in the scenario you are presented with.

Comment: Of course I am not referring to a guide such as that, but I see a lot of features and technologies being overlooked due to the lack of exposure and the difficulty of entry without knowledge. For example, look at how many companies are testing on hundreds of VM's in the cloud using browserstack at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

We already do have such resource, it is called "Google" :-)

Now seriously: feel free to blog about your interests, but you cannot predict reliably interest of other people, and tasks they need to solve. If you can, **that** should be your business, and not blogging about QA :-)

Your selected path to learn advanced stuff might be optimal for you (or might not - you don't know what you don't know, famous "unknown unknowns" of Donald Rumsfeld), but your optimal path very likely will not match interests and needs of others.

So don't try to "cater to advanced learning". Post about what you learned, and if you post good material, people will find your best posts (using Google), and may even read some others.

You are competing for attention with many thousands of very smart people, chances are that even if you are extremely smart, there are few people smarter than you (and that is OK). On Internet, information has a [long tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail), but because audience is so huge, even most obscure bits of info have some value to someone. You just cannot know for whom.

And of course I can also be wrong - I was wrong before, and sure I will be again. Prove me wrong! Go ahead and create a blog with excellent resources for learning!